# Insert variable inside custom made type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type in Typescript that looks like

```
export type = ProjectNames = 'project1' | 'project2' | 'project3';
```

When I hover over the type, I get a tooltip that says `type ProjectNames = "project1" | "project2" | "project3"`. What I have now is a const variable from a different file with a value of `const a = 'project1'`. My goal here is to replace my `project1` from the type with `a`, so I can have

```
export type = ProjectNames = typeof a | 'project2' | 'project3';
```

However, when I hover now I get a tooltip that says `type ProjectNames = string`, which I guess is not a type that I've defined.

Is there a way to replace one string that defines the type with a variable whose value is the same as the before-mentioned string?

Edit for more details. I get this `const a` from an `.env` file so `a` is value from my environment file. Some components use `a` as type `string` but having `process.env.a`, gets me `string | undefined` and the components that use `a` as `string` start to throw error. In that case I cast this `a` into `string`.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5ABwE4gFYFNhQCMKA3AFBm4AeaIGsUAnmrjAApZ4EBycAtrghIYTFiABm8GAB9UmHPigAmFDLmdFAZlJA)

Comment: Same here. Also, did you mean: export type ProjectNames = typeof a | 'project2' | 'project3';

Comment: I have it just like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5ABwE4gFYFNhQCMK8EM0GAlmAOYDcAUA7gB5ogaxQCeauMABSx4CAOTgBbXGWQ8%20IAGbwYAH1SYc%20KACYSa9MK0BmFHSA @slideshowp2

Comment: Works fine for me but you could try adding 'as const'

export const a = 'project1' as const

Comment: In your playground, you have `const a = 'project1' as string;` You explicitly widened your type to `string`

Comment: Yes, because `const a` is a value from an `.env` and some components use strictly `string` as type for `a`. Bear in mind that `a` is a value that I use in a few components and the goal here is for different project, different values. However, this type that has `a` in it throws the described error which I'm trying to solve, if possible @Lesiak